# Display Avatar for solspace rating

Tags: members, solspace, solspace-rating

this may be a dumb question im slightly new to EE and have read the docs for Solspace rating plugin. Basically I have a ratings for trainers. But the avatar being displayed is of the user id that i am on the {name} is fine is displaying the right name for this rating just the avatar is the same for all..

here is my code

```
{exp:rating:entries
    entry_id="{entry_id}"
    limit="10"
}

    <p>{review}</p>

    <ul>
        <p>{stars}{rating}{/stars}</p>

    {if screen_name}
    <h6>{name}</h6>

    {if avatar}
    <img src="{avatar_url}" width="{avatar_width}" height="{avatar_height}"  />
    {/if} 
    </ul>


    {if rating_no_results}
        <p>Sorry, no ratings have been submitted for this entry yet.</p>
    {/if}

{/exp:rating:entries}
```

Comment: Hi , I don't know if this related with your problem but I don't see a closed tag for {if screen_name} add it and check if your code works, and check the users avatars in your CMS to be sure it's difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is correct (unless you're missing the closing {/if} for the screen name check like Ahmad pointed out). However, I am assuming you have this Rating:Entries tag placed inside a Channel:Entries loop, within the same template?

If so, what's happening is that variables between the 2 tags are colliding, and you'll need to use an embed instead:

Main template:

```
{exp:channel:entries ...stuff... }
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <p>{body}</p>
    {embed="path_to/embed_template" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Embedded template:

```
{exp:rating:entries
    entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"
    limit="10"
}
    <p>{review}</p>
    <p>{stars}{rating}{/stars}</p>
    <h6>{name}</h6>
    {if avatar}
    <img src="{avatar_url}" width="{avatar_width}" height="{avatar_height}"  />
    {/if} 
    </ul>
    {if rating_no_results}
        <p>Sorry, no ratings have been submitted for this entry yet.</p>
    {/if}
{/exp:rating:entries}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly but now iv made it a bit tricky, I want to use my own custom fieldtype in my channel, how can I pull the images in this case?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You want to use a custom field in {exp:channel:entries}? It should be as simple as calling its name, eg. {my_custom_channel_field}. For EE File Upload fields, you might want to read this documentation to display uploaded files/images in a channel entry: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/custom_fields.html#file-field